# What is the shortest way to generate a Hello World Exe file from a JSP webpage?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, compilation, ejb

**Scenario :**

When some one enter to my website at : **www.domain.com/mypage.jsp** he will find an input text box to type his name, and a download button. 
When the user enter his name and hit the download button, he will be redirected to a link where he can download an executable file that works under windows, when the exe is clicked, the user will see a hello world message.

---

The question : In which programming language should I write the "Hello World Executable" in the way that let me EASILY make some modifications in its source and compile it from the JSP webpage.

It would be highly appreciated if you share any examples on how to compile a small Hello World exe from a JSP webpage, what libraries i need to import, and which language is easier to be compiled from a JSP web page.

Comment: pretty much any language which uses plaintext source files and has a compiler would work. simple search/replace on the source, compile, done.

Comment: @MarcB Not true. The challenge here is finding a compiler that produces .exe files which isn't dependent upon non-native external libraries, for the OS that the OP runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most difficult part of this is finding a programming language that has an existing cross-compiler platform, which will compile .exe files on whatever OS your server runs. This isn't difficult if your server runs Windows. The problem here is that we're not sure which OS you're running. Without guessing, a solution seems to exist in the form of VB (however unfortunate that is). Your server would never have to modify the source code. Your code might look something like:

```
Module mainModule
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello " & Name & ". Press enter to exit.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

To compile this, the server could invoke the Microsoft VB compiler or the Mono VB compiler as a shell command, using the `/define:` switch to define Name. Make sure you sanitise the name before you put it into a command! Make sure it doesn't contain any characters that the command line might interpret undesirably, like pipe characters, newlines and quotation marks.

The Mono command: `vbnc filename.vb /define:Name=\"Fred\" /out:Fred.exe`

The Microsoft command: `vbc filename.vb /define:Name=\"Fred\" /out:Fred.exe`

If, by chance, your server happens to run Windows, then you could invoke the Microsoft C++ compiler to achieve the same affect with C code. This isn't much better. Perhaps, with some success, you might be able to copy `cl.exe` from a Windows environment into a Linux (or otherwise non-Windows) environment, and run it using WINE. If that's the case, I'd prefer that option. Your source code might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("Hello " NAME ". Press enter to exit");
    getchar();
}
```

... and the command would look something like: `wine cl.exe filename.c /DNAME="Fred" /out:Fred.exe`, with the same precautions necessary to prevent malicious users from hijacking your system.